# keep $_FILES info during validation

Tags: php, file

So I want to make a form to upload/email files in PHP. I've got the form working pretty well, validation santization, all those goodies.. however I've got a small stumbling block, if the file is valid but some of the other data (email address for example) is not, I lose the file information during validation.
Maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: store $_FILE in $_SESSION? (and save the file somewhere where it isn't deleted when the script finished)

Comment: I dont see any nicer option than what @GeraldSchneider suggested.

Comment: You will need to do what @GeraldSchneider mentioned or save the file elsewhere in a way that when the form is re-sent you know what file belongs with it and use it. Down side with that is you will need to manage deleting files that get left over (Abandoned forms). You will need to use one of these solutions because file uploads are temporary. The sever deletes them after script execution if they are still around; in the interest of teaching a complete principle, just know there are exceptions to this rule.